# Progress bar for sending binary files in Websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is there a way to track how many bytes have been sent through a `Websocket` connection, so I can show a progress bar.

For example I want to send an image. I already know the image size, I just need to have an event on how many bytes have been transferred in the last second for example or something similar.

Here is my code

```
//html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="input">

//js
var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
function handleFiles() {
    var fileList = this.files;

    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    connection.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
    connection.onopen = () => {
        connection.send(fileList[0]);
    };
}
```

Comment: The [WebSocket API](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/) does not provide events for accomplishing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to do this with `WebSocket.bufferedAmount` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

> The number of bytes of data that have been queued using calls to
>   send() but not yet transmitted to the network. This value resets to
>   zero once all queued data has been sent. This value does not reset to
>   zero when the connection is closed; if you keep calling send(), this
>   will continue to climb.

```
function sendBinary(binMsg, callback) {
        ws.send(binMsg);

        if (callback != null) {
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (ws.bufferedAmount > 0) {
                    callback(ws.bufferedAmount)
                } else {
                    callback(0)
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

then I would call the method like this

```
var file = fileList[0];
sendBinary(file , function(bytesNotSent){
    if(amount==0){
       console.log('file sent');
    }else{
       var loaded = file.size - bytesNotSent;
       var percentage = Math.round((loaded * 100) / file.size );
       console.log(percentage);
    }
});
```

I've tested this in `Chrome 58`, `Firefox 53` and `Edge 14` and here is my conclusion on how `bufferedAmount` is handled:

- `Chrome 58` - constantly updates `bufferedAmount` when bytes are sent
- `Firefox 53` - updates `bufferedAmount` only when the file is sent ( 
  in Firefox `bufferedAmount` has only 2 values `file.size` and `0`
- `Edge 14` - updates `bufferedAmount` after 1MB of data is sent

*NOTE*: if you send multiple files `bufferedAmount` will return the amount of unsent bytes from all those files

Comment: Note: When using sendBinary() you should wait until bufferedAmount is 0 again, otherwise, calling sendBinary() subsequently results in a endless callback loop, as bufferedAmount will never reach 0 if you keep the connection always busy. That's the drawback of using an interval.

Comment: It would be nice if there were plans to make this achievable in future, WebSocket.bufferedAmount is really a bit of a hack given it will start to get very dicey as soon as you have more then 1 send() running a time.

Ideally something as simple as websocket.send(data, progressCallback); seems reasonable.

Comment: `if(amount==0)` where is `amount`? it's not coming from the callback